# how to remove static session and static cookie in c# using web request

Tags: session, c#-4.0, cookies, static, session-cookies

i have static variable in each page. after login, info is storing in session variables. These session variables r storing in static variables of each page while loading.

```
    if session expires i can get thru static variables. Problem is after logout n login again these static variable r existing. help me to reset static variables.. or any other solution for my problem?

    OverallStaticSession.Session.clear();
    OverallStaticSession.cookie.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in ASP.NET to abandon sessions like -

```
Session.Abandon();
```

Also, you can clear off the cookie values using below code -

```
if (Request.Cookies["userId"] != null)
{
    Response.Cookies["userId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);   
}
```

Note : You cannot directly delete a cookie on a user's computer. However, you can direct the user's browser to delete the cookie by setting the cookie's expiration date to a past date. The next time a user makes a request to a page within the domain or path that set the cookie, the browser will determine that the cookie has expired and remove it.

Comment: autullay i am using window application using c#

Comment: how can clear cookie and session in window application

Comment: @SATHISHkumar... it doesnt matter what type of application you are using. This feature will work as it is C# language specific.

Comment: I am using windows with c# 4.0

Comment: @SATHISHkumar.. you can add a reference to System.Web System namespace in your WinForms application and then use Session class like                                      "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();"